# monitoring threadpool status in external library

Tags: java, jvm, threadpool, monitoring

I want to monitor a thread pool which is used in an external library in java environment.

It is possible to add monitoring logic on a pool object like ExecuterService defined in my own code.
But many cases, pools declared in libraries are encapsulated, so users cannot reach. 
I need to keep checking resources consumed by library pools to make my program stable.

The features that I want to monitor are pool's name, size, current usage such as number of active threads etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation classes for `ExecutorService`, like `ThreadPoolExecutor`? What information do you want to monitor that you cannot get using one of the getters of this class?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thank u for the reply. I can get information by calling getter methods of ThreadPoolExecutor when the executor object is accessible. But I am asking the case when the object is not reachable cause the external library declared it encapsulates it, not to be revealed outside the library.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a custom ThreadGroup and make this default thread group of your thread(s).  The advantage of a custom thread group is that it is notified when a Thread is created or destroyed and you can obtain a stack trace of the library creating the thread.

To monitor a ThreadPoolExecutor directly you need to modify this class or use instrumentation to inject code into it.

It is more likely to be easier to inject code into the library e.g. via decompiling the class creating the pool and modifying it.

Another option is it may be possible to obtain the ExecutorService via reflection.